# How to troubleshoot a video freeze

Tags: kernel, xorg, dell, gpu-driver

System information:

- Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
- Gnome 3.12.2
- kernel **4.0.0-997-generic** #201503310205 SMP Tue Mar 31 02:07:04 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux (this is an updated *drm/intel-next* kernel from [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/drm-intel-next/))
- Module intel:

  - vendor="X.Org Foundation compiled for 1.15.1
  - version = 2.99.917.

The above kernel and driver were suggested by the *intel-gfx* mailing list. The box itself is a **Dell Optiplex 780**.

The problem that I've been experiencing since December of last year is periodically the video will lockup for no known reason.

I had submitted a bug report [#1402331](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1402331) and also contributed information to the one at freedesktop.org [#75394](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=75394)

The last time the Hangcheck...error showed up was 19 March of this year however since then there have been numerous occasions where I would notice a black screen with just a movable mouse cursor. Other times the video would freeze when browsing using *Firefox*. In both instances I'd be able to `CTRL>ALT>F1` into a console and reboot.  The below was suggested by the *intel-gfx* list:

```
That's unfortunate. Not a GPU hang then. The next task is then to
inspect each process and see who is stuck talking to X: either going to
be unity (or compiz, gnome-shell etc) or the xscreensaver. And then try
and figure out the best way to postmortem it given that we are looking
for a missing piece of chatter.

A stacktrace (both user/kernel just in case) for X, unity would probably
be the next step.
```

I have gone here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Backtracing and attempted to use the first option after a freeze happens.

Here is my `kern.log` from two freezes that happened on 10 May and 13 May. I don't know if any information there will be helpful or not - http://paste.ubuntu.com/11226544/.

Here is the output of `sudo lshw` - http://paste.ubuntu.com/11226588/.

My `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` - http://paste.ubuntu.com/11226839/.

So, my question after all of the above is just how do I further troubleshoot this problem? I can replicate it just by turning on X-Screensaver again.

Comment: How hot does your computer feel when it freezes?

Comment: That is part of the problem, when the freeze happens I have to CTRL>ALT>F1 into a console and reboot. I guess I could load LMSENSORS and pull that info up from a console.

Comment: I mean physically. Touch the bottom of the computer once it freezes.

Comment: I removed my previous reply to ask this - what is touching the bottom of the case going to tell me when I replicate the freeze?

Comment: If it feels really warm, it's an overheating issue, and your graphics card is crashing. You can then use the TTY to check the temperatures.

Comment: You are using a recent kernel but as it is related to graphic driver I would rather try to use the latest one available at `ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers`. These are the latest from intel dev. They are quite stable most of the time. Use `ppa-purge` to remove that **ppa** if you latter change your mind.

Comment: Thanks but I would rather stay with the driver I'm using that was suggested by those on the intel-gfx list.  As I said above what I really want to do is the stacktrace asked for but I'm not sure just exactly how to go about it. I don't even know if the output in the kern.log that I linked to above shows anything.

Comment: You could add `drm.debug=6` to your kernel command line (grub), run update-grub, reboot, reproduce the issue and attach your `dmesg`, `Xorg.0.log`. Don't forget to revert this after to avoid big logs. I recommend again to try the oibaf ppa.

Comment: I'll give that a try. Here is where I got the driver I'm currently using:                                                                                                                                                $ sudo apt-get build-dep xserver-xorg-video-intel
    $ git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/xorg/driver/xf86-video-intel
    $ cd xf86-video-intel
    $ ./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr
    $ make && sudo make install

Answer (score 0):

I do get this as well from time to time. Using the console not to reboot, but to find out what is happening revealed that it was a problem with compiz for me.

The solution was to kill compiz and then return to the graphical console. Compiz would be restarted and everything was back to normal.

To kill compiz via the console, type the following on the commandline:

```
killall -KILL compiz
```

After that use Ctrl-Alt-F7 to return to your graphical session wich will automatically restart compiz for you and you can continue without reboot.